# How to increment the value in Hash/Object without pre-defining them

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am working on Rails project

I have a Hash of products with their unique codes as keys

```
products = [
    {"dt": "2016-01-01",
     "quantity": 122,
     "amount": 123000
    },
    {"dt": "2016-01-02",
     "quantity": 97,
     "amount": 97800
    }
    {"dt": "2016-01-03",
     "quantity": 142,
     "amount": 163000
    }
]
```

My objective is to create the sum of quantity of these 3 days report. I iterate through the object. I want to add new attribute to each of the object inside the array named "total_quantity" which is increased in each iteration.

```
products.each do |row|
    rowqty += row['quantity']
    rowamount += row['amount']
    row['total_quantity'] = rowqty
    row['total_amount'] = rowamount
end
```

You can see that I define two additional variables "rowqty" and "rowamount" to hold the updated data before using them to create the new attributes of each object.

But i get this error

```
undefined method `+' for nil:NilClass
```

However, if I pre-define the variables before the iteration, it seems to work. Like this

```
rowqty = 0
rowamount = 0

products.each do |row|
    rowqty += row['quantity']
    rowamount += row['amount']
    row['total_quantity'] = rowqty
    row['total_amount'] = rowamount
end
```

I understand that it requires the variable existence in order to do something with it. But I have to confess that I can see that I will encounter with such a problem when the data becomes much more complicated.

So is there anyway to apply mathematical operations like increase, decrease or whatever with the variables that do not exit in the scope?

In PHP, it seems to create the new variable at the point. This includes arrays and objects. But I can not do it in Rails

Comment: Just a nit-pick on your tag selection: Even though you may be doing this as part of a Rails project, this is purely a Ruby question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In PHP, an undefined variable will default to `0` and be instantiated for you when you first try to add something to it.

```
$unknown_var += 1;   // This works!
```

In Ruby you will get an error if you try to do the same thing, so you must define your variable before you can increment it:

```
known_var = 0
known_var += 1   # This works, but not if you don't define your variable first
```

In answer to your question, you will simply need to define your variables before you can use them. Critically, you *MUST* define your variable outside of the scope generated within your loop, otherwise the variable will reset each time your loop runs and you will not be able to perform your sum calculation across your array the way you are.

Your final example in your question is the correct way to do this without using something more complicated like `inject`.

As per Sema's answer, using inject you could implement the same summing, but don't forget to also modify your initial dataset:

```
products.inject([0, 0]) do |data, product|
  data[0] += product['quantity']
  data[1] += product['amount']
  product['total_quantity'] = data[0]
  product['total_amount'] = data[1]
  data
end
```

However, this will still define a local variable when you call `inject` and will increment the values within it upon each iteration of your array.

Incidentally, testing the speed of these two options shows your original solution to be the fastest:

```
Calculating -------------------------------------
    Using Array#each    36.667k i/100ms
  Using Array#inject    31.819k i/100ms
-------------------------------------------------
    Using Array#each    427.696k (± 7.8%) i/s -      2.127M
  Using Array#inject    362.753k (± 4.2%) i/s -      1.814M

Comparison:
    Using Array#each:   427695.7 i/s
  Using Array#inject:   362753.2 i/s - 1.18x slower
```

Code used to generate this benchmark: https://gist.github.com/pacso/f7e997593bd15bd121d1

Comment: Good answer. Its awesome that you actually took the time to profile each vs inject.

Comment: Thanks @max - curiosity got the better of me on that one ;)

Answer (score 2):

From your description "when the data becomes much more complicated", it looks like the inventory of variables may frequently change during code development. This is a case where you should not keep individual variables but have a single hash holding all of them.

And if you do so, it is easy to achieve what you are asking for. `h = Hash.new(0)` will initialize a hash with all its potential keys being initialized to `0` automatically when syntactic sugar methods like `+=` are called.

```
h = Hash.new(0)
products.each do |row|
  h[:rowqty] += row['quantity']
  h[:rowamount] += row['amount']
  row['total_quantity'] = rowqty
  row['total_amount'] = rowamount
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use method [reduce](http://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerable/reduce) for array:

```
# returns array of 2 elements with summary values
def calculate_sums(products)
  products.reduce([0, 0]) do |sum, product|
    sum[0] += product['quantity']
    sum[1] += product['amount']
    sum
  end
end

# somewhere in source code
total_quantity, total_amount = calculate_sums(products)
```

Not sure, that this code is better than the case of local variables :)

Little explanation: `reduce` accepts initial value `[0, 0]` and iterate over array with injecting `sum` variable into each iteration.

PS. If your `products` variable comes from ActiveRecord, the neat way to [calculate sums](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Calculations/ClassMethods/sum) would be like

```
products.sum('quantity')
products.sum('amount')
```